# How to delete one sprite from a group(list), while it is iterating?

Tags: python, pygame

***I want that if a bullet is touching (ghost), the one ghost from the group(list) would disappear. Here is a part of the code. Ps; I'm sorry for my previous questions***

```py
import pygame, math, random, os

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
     def __init__(self, x, y, direction):
        super().__init__() 
         self.x = x + 15
         self.y = y + 25
         self.fx = 10
         self.fy = 10
         self.direction = direction

     def draw_bullet(self, screen):
         screen.blit(bullet_img, (self.x, self.y))

      def move(self):
          if self.direction == 1:
              self.x += 15
         if self.direction == -1:
             self.x -= 15                  
      def off_screen(self):
          return not(self.x >= 0 and self.x <= width)
           
          def update(self):
              self.rect.x += 5
   class Ghost(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, x, y, fx,fy):
           pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.image = pygame.image.load('ghost.png').convert_alpha()
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect() 
            self.rect.x = x
            self.rect.y = y
            self.fartx = fx
            self.farty = fy 

     lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
     for i in range(len(lst)): 
     ghost = Ghost(random.randint(0,width),random.randint(0,height),random.randint(1,8),random.randint(1,8))
             ghostgruppe.add(ghost)
    
    ghosttruffet = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(ghostgruppe, bulletgruppe, True, True, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)
```

Comment: `pygame.sprite.groupcollide(ghostgruppe, bulletgruppe, True, True, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)` should do what you want. What is the problem?

Comment: I want to delete only 1 ghost, not all the ghosts when a bullet is touching a ghost.

Answer (score 0):

If the Glosts overlap and you just want to delete the fist ghost touching the bullet, you need to pass `False` to the `dokill1`  argument of [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) and manually [`kill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) the first ghost:

```py
ghosttruffet = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(
    ghostgruppe, bulletgruppe, False, True, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)
if ghosttruffet:
    list(ghosttruffet.keys())[0].kill()
```

See [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide):

> Every Sprite inside group1 is added to the return dictionary. The value for each item is the list of Sprites in group2 that intersect.

Comment: Thanks, but the whole group get deleted. I think it something in for loop should be changed, because there are the ghosts created.

Comment: @Mhmm. No. You are wrong. Do you create the ghosts in ever frame? Anyway your question and code is completely unclear.

Comment: Sorry, should I make the question better? Maybe I will try to explain: the for i in range loop creates 8 the same group of sprites(ghosts),  if 1 ghost from the loop is touching a bullet, the one single ghost (from the loop) will delete. #That is what I want to have, but maybe is not possible, very sorry. Yes, I create the ghosts in ever frame

Comment: @Mhmm. Please accept that my code does exactly what you want it to do. If it doesn't work for you, you messed up something else in your project.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks.  Omg, sorry! I think I have found that problem because: My game has 2 backgrounds and now I have find out that on the secound background it does work. Very sorry.